# Using own Facebook access token to query data to populate a databse

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

I'm building an application which will query certain kinds of events from facebook, store those events in a database, and use that database to populate a website listing the events. I want to use this route because Facebook requires user authorization in order to query for public events, and I don't want users to have to use their own access tokens to get the data (that would limit my audience dramatically).

So my question is - is there a way that I can programmatically get my access token server side? And how can I make it last longer than a day? I'm using node.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of data you're fetching, the most suitable approach is probably to use an app access token. Alternatively, you can generate a long-lived user access token using API calls. Both of these are documented here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens